# How could I get numpy array indices by some conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I come to a problem like this: 
suppose I have arrays like this:

`a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],])
label = np.array([[1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],])`

I need to obtain the indices of `a` at which position the element value of `label` is 1 and the value of `a` is the largest amount all that causing `label` to be 1.

It maybe confusing, in the above example, the indices where `label` is  1 are: 0, 2, 5, 6, 8, their corresponding values of `a` are thus: 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, among which 4 is the larges, thus I need to get the result of 5 which is the index of number 4 in `a`. How could I do this with numpy ?

Answer (score 3):

Get the `1s` indices say as `idx`, then index into `a` with it, get `max` index and finally trace it back to the original order by indexing into `idx` -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(label==1)
out = idx[a[idx].argmax()]
```

Sample run -

```
# Assuming inputs to be 1D
In [18]: a
Out[18]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

In [19]: label
Out[19]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])

In [20]: idx = np.flatnonzero(label==1)

In [21]: idx[a[idx].argmax()]
Out[21]: 5
```

For `a` as ints and `label` as an array of `0s` and `1s`, we could optimize further as we could scale `a` based on the range of values in it, like so -

```
(label*(a.max()-a.min()+1) + a).argmax()
```

Furthermore, if `a` has positive numbers only, it would simplify to -

```
(label*(a.max()+1) + a).argmax()
```

Timings for positive ints largish `a`  -

```
In [115]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000))
     ...: label = np.random.randint(0,2,(100000))

In [117]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = np.flatnonzero(label==1)
     ...: out = idx[a[idx].argmax()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 592 µs per loop

In [116]: %timeit (label*(a.max()-a.min()+1) + a).argmax()
1000 loops, best of 3: 357 µs per loop

# @coldspeed's soln
In [120]: %timeit np.ma.masked_where(~label.astype(bool), a).argmax()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

# won't work with negative numbers in a
In [119]: %timeit (label*(a.max()+1) + a).argmax()
1000 loops, best of 3: 292 µs per loop

# @klim's soln (won't work with negative numbers in a)
In [121]: %timeit np.argmax(a * (label == 1))
1000 loops, best of 3: 229 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use masked arrays:

```
>>> np.ma.masked_where(~label.astype(bool), a).argmax()
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the simplest ways.

```
>>> np.argmax(a * (label == 1))
5
>>> np.argmax(a * (label == 1), axis=1)
array([5])
```

Coldspeed's method may take more time.

Comment: What if there are negative numbers in `a`?

Comment: Divakar. Yes this will not work if there are negatives numbers in `a` and if there is no match in `label`.

Comment: Still pretty fast under the constraints, going by the timings just added.